# Clearing device owner application data

Tags: android, device-owner

I'm developing a [device owner app](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#isDeviceOwnerApp%28java.lang.String%29) (which is installed via QR code) In one scenario I need to switch users and that involves clearing all data that is related to the application, if the app wasn't a "device owner app" I would use android

```
((ActivityManager) m_context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();
```

but since it is a "device owner app" I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot clear data for a protected package

Are there any other api / approach to clear data for device owner application?

---

Update:

Thanks to [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) I called `context.deleteDatabase("db_name")` to all db's and cleared all SharedPreferences like this

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    return editor.commit();
```

And that's was enough...

Comment: Why not just delete your files? It is your app, You know what files it is creating and where.

Comment: I'm trying to clear all SharedPreferences that I stored in the app but nothing clears them :| (tried all available / known to me commands)

Comment: If [`clear()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#clear()) is not working for you, file a bug report, I guess. You could iterate over all of the values in the `SharedPreferences` and delete them individually as well. In both cases, you need to `commit()` or `apply()` the `Editor` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @CommonsWare , thanks for your comments, eventually that what I did (delete your files + clear & commit , and it works (long story why It didn't work for the first time I was trying it) , please post it as an answer so I can accept it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear your data "the hard way", by deleting the files that you created or clearing their contents.

You may want to examine your app's portion of internal storage via Android Studio's Device File Manager or `adb shell`, to see if there are other files that need to be cleared that you did not create directly (e.g., from `WebView`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#clearApplicationUserData(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.OnClearApplicationUserDataListener)) if you are the device owner on an Android 9 Pie device (SDK 28 required):

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) 
    this.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
Componentname mDeviceAdminRcvr = 
    new ComponentName(this, YourDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
mDPM.clearApplicationUserData(
            mDeviceAdminRcvr, 
            String packageName, 
            Executor executor, 
            DevicePolicyManager.OnClearApplicationUserDataListener listener)
```

But I think it is meant to clear data on other applications.

Can you explain why you need to clear data from your device owner app on a user switch? There might be another way to do what you need to do since you'd be switching to a secondary user anyways. My implementations have just needed to create/delete users (prior to ephemeral users) and then configure the user using AE APIs and their apps via managed configurations.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that one, but it doesn't look to work on the app itself but rather on other apps, by telling "switch user" I meant my internal app (local logic...) users and not android users

Comment: dwn for providing non working solution while op asked  clear user data of device owner app

Comment: I want this implementation, can you please share a fully working example?